# How to force app to go Fullscreen (Notch-Friendly)

Tags: android, kotlin

I having having problem during the fullscreen, As some of the devices Notch Area becomes blank and shows black screen. I can manually force the app for fullscreen but I want to know how to make it programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a new values-v28 folder in your res directory and copy the default styles.xml file into it.
2. In the values-v28 variant of the styles.xml file, go to your activity’s theme or create a new one if you’ve been using the default one, and set this attribute:

```
<style name="ActivityTheme">
  <item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode">
    shortEdges
  </item>
</style>
```

That's It, Your app won't show that black screen around the notch anymore

Comment: Thanks dude, You're a life Saver